# Chartjs - Insert labels at xAxes

Tags: charts, chart.js

i need help for develop my chart, my doubt is how build labels dynamic from datasets.

My code:

```js
public lineChart: any = {
  type: 'line',
  datasets: [{
   label: 'Dólar Alvo',
   data: [{ x: '18/02/2020 08:00', y: 4.1000 }, { x: '18/02/2020 09:00', y: 4.1000 }],
   fill: false,
   
  }, {
   label: 'Dólar Hub',
   data: [{ x: '18/02/2020 08:00', y: 4.1200 }, { x: '18/02/2020 09:00', y: 4.1300 }, { x: '18/02/2020 10:00', y: 4.1400 }, { x: '18/02/2020 11:00', y: 4.1250 }],
   fill: false,
  }, {
   label: 'Taxa PTAX',
   data: [{ x: '18/02/2020 08:00', y: 4.1500 }, { x: '18/02/2020 09:00', y: 4.1700 }, { x: '18/02/2020 10:00', y: 4.1900 }, { x: '18/02/2020 11:00', y: 4.3250 }],
   fill: false,
  }],
  options: {
   legend: {
    onClick: function () { return }
   },
   tooltips: {
    enabled: false
   },
   scales:{
   
    
   }
   
  }
 }
```

I hope insert label from range date datasets.data.x, i tried everything, but i don't have success in the my actions :///

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found that's solution for my problem:

```js
 scales: {
    xAxes: [{
     type: "time",
     time: {
      unit: 'day',
      unitStepSize: 1,
      displayFormats: {
       'day': 'DD MMM'
      }
     },
     ticks: {
      // maxRotation: 0 ,
      major: {
       enabled: true,
       fontStyle: 'bold',
       fontSize: 14,
       callback: function (value, index, values) {
        if (values[index] !== undefined) {
         if (values[index].major == true) {
          return moment(values[index].value).format('DD MMM');
         }
         else {
          return value;
         }
        }
       }
      },
     },



    }],
```